# Workflow with purchased sound effects library?

Tags: library, library-sound-effects, metadata, database, embed

Hi all,

Sorry for sounding like a noob 'cos I have a noob question. :`( I've just purchased my first sound effects libraries (from Sound Ideas) and they came in audio CDs. I know that there are softwares and Tab Delimited ASCII Text Files from the Sound Ideas that I should use to create metadata for the sound effects, but...

Firstly, what do you guys do to bring the files onto your hard drive? Secondly, after bringing the files to the hard drive, what do you guys use to add/embed the provided metadata csv or ascii text files to the files?

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS. What I tried was to use iTunes to create wav files and the metadata iTunes use are brief excerpts and not the full description that I can find from the delimited text files. But somehow I couldn't find any ways out of trial-and-error of automatically embedding the full descriptions that are right there on my textedit into my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there and welcome!

Gareth Fry describes his workflow on his blog:

http://garethfry.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/creating-a-sound-effects-library-with-metadata/

Good luck!

Arnoud Traa

Answer (score 0):

I use Soundminer for assets management.  they have a ripper tool which is a discontinued legacy product, altough talking to Steve there might give you an avenue to purchase it.  It rips the tracks and embeds the metadata into the files themselves which is then displayable in Soundminer.  While it is only one of many ways to digitize and infuse the files with metadata, it is widely regarded as the most widely used and effective method of choice (espeially with Soundminer being the popular choice of assetd management).  Basebead I believe has similar functionality.